# Determine if input object is a ctypes object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to determine if an input object to a function is a `ctypes` object. It looks like, based on the ctypes class hierarchy that, there is a class that all `ctypes` objects inherit from called `_CData`.

I've found its location in the `_ctypes` source code on [line 2911](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2780df478129c4f1042df2868b6adf2bf507cd6e/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L2911) of `_ctypes.c`, but I can't seem to `import` it from either the `ctypes` or `_ctypes` libraries. Is there a way to `import` this object so that I can use it or is there an alternate way to check if an input is a `ctypes` object?

Comment: Follow the chain of base classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

*_ctypes._CData* is a non public class, that can't be imported (**!!! beware, there may be a good reason for this !!!**) directly. 
However, we can get it using a workaround involving *_ctypes._SimpleCData* (also non public - according to *doc*) which is one of its direct descendants:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>> ct.c_int.__mro__
> (<class 'ctypes.c_int'>, <class '_ctypes._SimpleCData'>, <class '_ctypes._CData'>, <class 'object'>)
> >>> ct.Structure.__mro__
> (<class '_ctypes.Structure'>, <class '_ctypes._CData'>, <class 'object'>)
> >>> ct._SimpleCData.__mro__
> (<class '_ctypes._SimpleCData'>, <class '_ctypes._CData'>, <class 'object'>)
> >>> CData = ct._SimpleCData.__mro__[-2]
> >>>
> >>> CData, type(CData)
> (<class '_ctypes._CData'>, <class 'type'>)
> >>>
> >>> isinstance(ct.c_int(1), CData)
> True
> >>>
> >>> class S0(ct.Structure): pass
> ...
> >>> s0 = S0()
> >>>
> >>> isinstance(s0, CData)
> True
> >>> isinstance(s0, ct._SimpleCData)
> False
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Given its restricted nature, if I used an alternative is this the best way?
`isinstance(obj, (ctypes._SimpleCData, ctypes._Pointer, ctypes.Array, ctypes.Structure, ctypes.Union)):`
I'm not a fan of how verbose it is.

Comment: According to docs (and common knowledge) all classes starting with *_* are not public. So, I don' t think that enumerating them is better (even if they are available via imports).